# Obtener minutos por hora con registros en SQLServer (Timestamp)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una query en SQL Server que me devuelve una serie de valores (Fecha de inicio y fecha de fin de averías en una maquina):

| START_DATE | START_HOUR | START_MINUTE | END_DATE | END_HOUR | END_MINUTE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-09 | 12 | 16 | 2022-07-09 | 12 | 21 |
| 2022-07-09 | 8 | 53 | 2022-07-09 | 8 | 54 |
| 2022-07-09 | 10 | 20 | 2022-07-09 | 10 | 43 |
| 2022-07-09 | 8 | 38 | 2022-07-09 | 8 | 39 |
| 2022-07-09 | 12 | 18 | 2022-07-09 | 12 | 21 |
| 2022-07-09 | 8 | 39 | 2022-07-09 | 8 | 42 |
| 2022-07-09 | 12 | 12 | 2022-07-09 | 12 | 21 |

Necesito averiguar por hora cuántos minutos ha estado en fallo la máquina.

El problema viene porque al registrar el número de fallos, pueden pisarse unos a otros, p. ej: Un registro puede ser desde las 08:39 hasta las 08:42, y otro desde las 08:40 hasta las 08:45.
Realmente la máquina ha estado en fallo desde las 08:39 hasta las 08:45.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es una diferencia entre la menor fecha/hora de inicio de fallo y la mayor fecha/hora de finalizacion de los mismos:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,MIN(START_DATE),MAX(END_DATE)) FROM Tabla
```

- Donde START_DATE y END_DATE deben ser la fecha completa YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm

Otra sugerencia seria guardar las fecha en un solo campo del tipo DateTime. Esto es mas prolijo y facilitar mucho las consultas.

Saludos.